# How to set Font in ListPicker FullScreen Mode

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, fonts, listpicker

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="PickerItemTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding BackGroundColorString}" />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Name="PickerFullModeItemTemplate" >
    <Grid x:Name="rootGrid" Margin="0" Background="Transparent">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Margin="0 14 0 0" Background="#FF030C34" >
            <TextBlock Name="BackgroundColor" 

                       Text="{Binding BackGroundColorString}"
                       Margin="0 0 480 0" 
                FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" 
                       TextAlignment="Left"
                      Foreground="White"
                       FontFamily="/Sunder Gutka;component/Assets/Fonts/AGENCYR.TTF#Agency FB"

                       />

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I have tried to use this code but fullscreen List Picker still comes in default font. how to set font in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing one from following:

- first of all check your font name is same as you are using in code
- have you set font property **Build Action -> Content**
- Check for its location you are giving in code is right or not

just use **FontFamily** Property like this:

```
   <TextBlock FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/Agency FB Regular.ttf#Agency FB"/>
```

It is in folder: \Assets\Fonts\Agency FB Regular.ttf and set Build Action "Content" and its working for me.

[image: Sample Image]

Answer (score 0):

increase font size in TextBlock `FontSize="25"` use it this code.

```
<TextBlock  Text="{Binding}" FontSize="25" Margin="10,10"/>
```